# Trying to Adapt PCRE Regular Expression for Use in .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pcre

I am developing a C# application to extract repeatable patterns out of an .x12 (txt) file. I have been able to build up a PCRE regex to accomplish the task, but having trouble adapting it to Regex for C#.

Below is the text that I am attempting to isolate:

```
HL*1**20*1~  
PER*IC*XX HEALTH XXXX XXXXX*TE*6822363000*FX*6822364615~  
NM1*87*2~  
N3*2448 XXXXX DR~  
N4*XXXX XXXX*XX*761089998~  
DMG*D8*19530804*F~  
NM1*PR*2*XXXXXX MEDICAL MANAGEMENT*****PI*95958~  
CLM*1111111111*3291.69***13:A:1**A*Y*Y~  
DTP*434*RD8*20160714-20160714~  
CL1*3*2*01~  
HCP*03*480.01~  
NM1*71*1*XXXXXXX*XXXXXXXX****XX*1111111111~  
SBR*P*18*UDF******CI~  
NM1*IL*1*XXXX*XXXXXXX*A***MI*509180801~  
LX*1~  
SV2*0250**44.19*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*0.00**0250*1~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
LX*2~  
SV2*0311*HC:88172*936.25*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*0.00*HC:88172*0311*1~  
CAS*CO*97*936.25~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
LX*3~  
SV2*0311*HC:88173*477.25*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*0.00*HC:88173*0311*1~  
CAS*CO*97*477.25~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
LX*4~  
SV2*0312*HC:88305*456.5*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*0.00*HC:88305*0312*1~  
CAS*CO*97*456.5~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
LX*5~  
SV2*0360*HC:10022*483.75*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*225.41*HC:10022*0360*1~  
CAS*PR*3*250~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
LX*6~  
SV2*0402*HC:76942*893.75*UN*1~  
DTP*472*D8*20160714~  
SVD*95958*0.00*HC:76942*0402*1~  
CAS*CO*97*893.75~  
DTP*573*D8*20160726~  
HL*3**20*1~ <-- FIND UP TO THIS LINE, BUT EXCLUDE FROM RESULTS
```

I know this is a long block of text. So, each regex match is to contain two lines that begin with HL and go to a line that begins with DTP that comes just before anther HL, but not including the Next HL.

Then PCRE regex that I am using in notepad++ is as follows. I have entered my understanding of it and goal afterword:

^HL(.+?)DTP(.+?)~(?=([\r\n]*HL))

1. start at the beginning of a line and look for an HL
2. match anything (including new lines and carriage returns) until you come to a  DTP followed by a tilde.
3. stop at the DTP with anything after it that ends with a tilde; AS LONG AS... that DTP line occurs before a subsequent line that begins with an HL. Further, exclude that next HL from the match.

I'm not sure how daunting this looks, but a push in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Your regex does not find any matches in the text you provided - https://regex101.com/r/eO7lD2/1

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Thanks for responding. That's my problem. It works in notepad++. But .NET does not use Pearl Compatible Regular Expressions like notepad++ does. I am trying to achieve in .NET what I have achieved in notepad++.

Comment: Notepad++ uses Boost regex, not PCRE. Your regex does not work in NPP, just checked. Both with the DOTALL modifier and without. Please double check what you are using, and what you posted. A couple of tips: 1) In NPP, `^` matches the start of a line, and in .NET, you need to use a Singleline flag (or add `(?m)` to the start of the pattern), 2) the *`.` matches newline* option in NPP is equal to passing a `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to the `Regex.Match` method, or use a `(?s)` inline modifier version at the start of the regex.

Comment: I think I got something here. I had the matches new line box checked. I think I need to correct for this in my expression.

Comment: Still no luck. Whew!

Comment: As I said, your posted regex does not match the sample data, neither with `/s`, nor without `/s`. Nor `/m`. Please add your real testing text/pattern that matches.

Comment: Regex isn't working in np++ or as PCRE in test regex: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: I'm getting closer. I am using the following: ^HL[\w\s\*~\.:\-,@()\r\n]*DTP[\w\*]*~[\r\n]*(?=(HL)), but it matches two blocks of the pattern instead of just one. I am trying to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Please post the real data you are testing against. Please make it concise.  I think the real pattern you are after is something like `(?sm)^HL\b(?:(?!\nHL\b).)*DTP[^\n]*~\s*?(?=\nHL\b)`. Or `(?m)^HL\b.*(?:\n(?!HL\b).*)*DTP.*~\s*?(?=\nHL\b)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to capture all DTP lines
The following regex documented by # for readability , is dotnet :

## PO Regex:  ^HL(.+?)DTP(.+?)~(?=([\r\n]*HL))

```
 ^HL                # strat with HL 
 .+?                 # any character ,one or more, as few as possible
 (
 (?<dtp>DTP.+?~)   # named group start with DTP
                              # any character ,one or more, as few as  possible
                             # ~
(.+?)
(?=DTP)    # match DTP but exclude it from capture
)+
```

I tested it at:
http://regexstorm.net/tester

The captured group are:

```
    DTP*434*RD8*20160714-20160714~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
    DTP*573*D8*20160726~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
    DTP*573*D8*20160726~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
    DTP*573*D8*20160726~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
    DTP*573*D8*20160726~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
    DTP*573*D8*20160726~
    DTP*472*D8*20160714~
```

Try it at:  http://regexstorm.net/tester

options: ignore whitespace /singleline/multiline

Comment: I doubt a lazy dot matching pattern will work here. If a block with the qualifying DTP is in the second block, the first and the second block will get matched.

Comment: @Wiktor, to stop the lazy dot matching (.+?) at DTP, i have to capture DTP in the second block but exclude it with the Patten  (?=DTP). If i removed the second block (?=DTP) , regex catch only one DTP. I tested the pattern at  http://regexstorm.net/tester  with the result given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for responding.
I was able to achieve what I was attempting with the following regular expression and wanted to follow up to maybe help someone out in the future.

^HL[\w\s*~.:-,@()\r\n]*?DTP[\w*]*~

Thanks Again